# get value from Dict in Django

Tags: python, django

given a dict:

```
context 
    {'department': <QuerySet [<DepartmentDetails: Administration>]>,
     'globalalert': <QuerySet []>,
     'globalmessage': <QuerySet []>,
     'next_task': {'instance': {'activityId': 'Process_B_PerProject:1:9481d86a-cc57-11ea-8be8-00155d891509',
                                'activityName': 'B Activites Per Project',
                                'activityType': 'processDefinition',
                                'childActivityInstances': [{'activityId': 'Task_5.1',
                                                            'activityName': '5.1 '
                                                                            'Assessment '
                                                                            'and '
                                                                            'Need',
                                                            'activityType': 'callActivity',
                                                            'childActivityInstances': [],
                                                            'childTransitionInstances': [],
                                                            'executionIds': ['9c3307e8-cc63-11ea-8be8-00155d891509'],
                                                            'id': 'Task_5.1:9c3307e9-cc63-11ea-8be8-00155d891509',
                                                            'name': '5.1 '
                                                                    'Assessment '
                                                                    'and Need',
                                                            'parentActivityInstanceId': '9c3292b0-cc63-11ea-8be8-00155d891509',
                                                            'processDefinitionId': 'Process_B_PerProject:1:9481d86a-cc57-11ea-8be8-00155d891509',
                                                            'processInstanceId': '9c3292b0-cc63-11ea-8be8-00155d891509'}],
                                'childTransitionInstances': [],
                                'executionIds': ['9c3292b0-cc63-11ea-8be8-00155d891509'],
                                'id': '9c3292b0-cc63-11ea-8be8-00155d891509',
                                'name': 'B Activites Per Project',
                                'parentActivityInstanceId': None,
                                'processDefinitionId': 'Process_B_PerProject:1:9481d86a-cc57-11ea-8be8-00155d891509',
                                'processInstanceId': '9c3292b0-cc63-11ea-8be8-00155d891509'}},
     'organisation': <QuerySet [<OrganisationDetails: Acme developments PLC>]>,
     'project': <QuerySet [<ProjectLive: ProjectLive object (30d44422-7b90-4b6b-ac88-fb52a4e3edb9)>, <ProjectLive: ProjectLive object (bea0ed54-a81e-4241-8cfd-0e60c66cdbf1)>]>,
     'result': {'process': {'businessKey': '57a4c7e9-fd9f-4d71-a39d-7bd8e112a39a',
                            'caseInstanceId': None,
                            'definitionId': 'Process_B_PerProject:1:9481d86a-cc57-11ea-8be8-00155d891509',
                            'ended': False,
                            'id': '9c3292b0-cc63-11ea-8be8-00155d891509',
                            'links': [{'href': 'http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-instance/9c3292b0-cc63-11ea-8be8-00155d891509',
                                       'method': 'GET',
                                       'rel': 'self'}],
                            'suspended': False,
                            'tenantId': None,
                            'variables': {'Organisation': {'type': 'String',
                                                           'value': '98901267-543b-4c02-be66-38252e857a3d',
                                                           'valueInfo': {}},
                                          'StartDate': {'type': 'String',
                                                        'value': '<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute '
                                                                 'object at '
                                                                 '0x04A364A8>',
                                                        'valueInfo': {}},
                                          'Startedby': {'type': 'String',
                                          … <trimmed 4283 bytes string>
```

I am trying to get the value of name within - context --> next_task -->instance -->childActivityInstances.

The method i used to get id from 'result' although not efficient works ok:

```
set_new = context['result']
    my_id = set_new.get('process')
    my_id1 = my_id.get('id')
```

This doesn't work for getting name as its enclosed within []

and i get a type error : list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access that member using:
`instances = context['next_task']['instance']['childActivityInstances']`

which will assign the list at that location to `instances`. If you need to get to the `childActivityInstances` at a deeper level, you can select a particular item in the list using it's index: `instances[0]` will return the first item, `instances[1]` the second item, etc. Then you can access the nested `childActivityInstances` using `instances[0]['childActivityInstances']`. You'll just need to follow the path of nesting.

Comment: it only ever returns one item from the API - luckily. after using the instances = context['next_task']['instance']['childActivityInstances'] ehich you suggested - how do i get into the activtyinstances to get the name as it has its own []. is for keys in instances ok then filter name or is there a more fficient way?

Comment: Then you can just bundle everything into one statement. `instances = context['next_task']['instance']['childActivityInstances'][0]['childActivityInstances']`

Comment: instances = context['next_task']['instance']['childActivityInstances'][0]['name'] work a treat - thank you